# How not include a reference from solution while preparing NuGet with IncludeReferencedProjects option

Tags: .net, dll, nuget, nuspec

I am producing a NuGet from several projects in a solution. One of the projects are required during the development process in the main project. (When I say main I mean the project which I run the nuget with IncludeReferencedProjects options) I do not want this project included in the nuget. However developmentDependency attribute is for packages only, not for DLLs from the solution. Is there a way to exclude this DLL from the NuGet?

A solution might be restructuring the solution and having no code in the main project, It only contains references to the projects which are needed in the NuGet.

Comment: Is it possible to make the development dependency as a NuGet package and consume it as such instead of refactoring the entire solution?

Comment: @HarikrishnaMenonA I am producing three nugets from a single solution. That one DLL is included in another nuget. Therefore I do not want to include it in this one. One solution might be separeting projects such that one nuget per solution. However that is cumbersome during development

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to make projects as developmental dependencies to my knowledge at this time. You could open a GitHub issue for this at http://github.com/nuget/home but I dont see us prioritizing this work at this time. Also, not sure how we would end up expressing this in proj file and map this to the project graph during pack as developmental dependency without some new MSBuild property.